# Custom Notification body not showing in iOS mobile app

Tags: process-builder, salesforce1-app, ios, custom-notification

I have created a custom notification and enabled it for both iOS and Android as shown below.

[image]

In my process builder, whenever the stage is changed to closed won, I should get a custom notification in iOS with title and body.

[image]

I also checked the connected app for iOS and noticed that "Display full content push notification" is already turned on.

[image]

Despite all that, I am only seeing the title and not the body in my iOS device. What could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: This should work, have you tried by reinstalling the app once or logout then login. Maybe the setting is cached at login (If you have enabled it recently) Android has a feature to show only title when phone is locked, not sure about iOS. Is the phone unlocked and the app running in foreground?

Comment: Tried to uninstall and reinstall the app and it’s still the same. I have checked iOS setting and enabled all notifications and it’s not a lock screen issue.